# Have FFMpeg output images more consistently when reading from a stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently seeing an issue where FFMPEG seems to write my images in bursts. When I run the following command:

`ffmpeg -i <URL> -vf fps=fps=1 -f image2 image-%d.png`

I get progress updates every two seconds, at which point immediately image-(n).png and image-(n+1).png are written in quick succession.

Is it possible to have these images output more consistently? I would prefer to have the output speed be the same as the designated FPS (so one image per second).

I am using a Python script to do some processing on these images and I am able to better maximize my throughput if these images came more consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add -re before -i to operate in real time. However I suspect the frames are being written regularly, just whatever method you are using to get fs updates is polled or coalesced

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I needed.